# Milling in Magic the Gathering Question

Tags: probability

Me and my friend were having an argument over whether milling in Magic the Gathering was always advantageous. I'm not a mathematician so I thought I'd get some insight if you'll be kind of enough to tackle my problem.

Now for those of you who don't know, Magic the Gathering is a card game where two players have a deck of cards each. The argument we had was very specific so I'll just make it abstract (so forget the Magic the Gathering bit really).

Your opponent has a deck of 30 cards, 10 of them are bad for them, 10 of them are neutral for them and 10 of them are good for them.

You can remove as many cards randomly from the deck (leaving at least 1 card).
Each time you remove a card you can look at it before deciding to continue removing cards or not.

Once you stop removing cards your opponent draws a random card from the deck.

The question is; is removing cards from the deck ever advantageous or disadvantageous or neither(what I think) with the objective of making your opponent draw as bad a card as possible?

Comment: You for sure should mill all his cards, because then he will lose during his next draw step ;)

Answer (score 1):

If we just focus on your opponent's next draw, it doesn't matter whether you mill or not.  You can imagine that he draws his card to play, then you remove as many cards as you want from his deck.  Clearly his play is not impacted.  What impact this has later on depends on rules that are not specified here.